Complex Modulus of a Function Symmetric About Real Axis
Suppose that $f:\Bbb C \rightarrow \Bbb C$. Is it true that $\lvert f(z) \rvert$ is symmetric about the real axis, that is, $\lvert f(z) \rvert = \lvert f(\bar{z})\rvert$?
This is true for $f(z) = z$, but I am not sure about other complex functions.

No. Let $f$ be the identity function everywhere except at $1+i$ and $1-i$ with $f(1+i)=0$ and $f(1-i)=1$.

Alternative: $~f(z) = z- i.~$ The easiest way to consider the posed question is by using the alternative definition of $~|f(z)|,~$ which represents the (non-negative) magnitude of the distance from $~f(z)~$ to $~0.$

Still another way of thinking about the problem is that $~f(\overline{z})~$ is not necessarily equal to $~\overline{f(z)}.$

Assume $f$ is entire and not identically zero and let $f(z)=\sum a_n z^n$.
$\lvert f(z) \rvert = \lvert f(\bar{z})\rvert$ is true if and only if there is (a unique) $|\lambda|=1$  such that $\bar a_n =\lambda a_n$ for all $n$ (so for example if $a_n$ are all real and $\lambda=1$)
Proof: if $f(z)=\sum a_n z^n$ satisfies $\bar a_n =\lambda a_n, |\lambda|=1$ then we have $\lambda f(z)=\overline{ f(\bar z)}$ since both sides are entire functions that coincide on $\mathbb R$. In particular, $|f(z)|=|f(\bar z)|$ since conjugate complex numbers have same modulus and $|\lambda|=1$
Conversely if $|f(z)|=|f(\bar z)|$ then with $g(z)=\overline{ f(\bar z)}$ entire, we have that $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$ which implies that $f,g$ have same zeroes with same multiplicity, so $g/f$ is entire and of modulus one, hence constant so $g=\lambda f, |\lambda|=1$. When we let $z=x \in \mathbb R$ so $g(x)=\sum \bar a_n x^n=\lambda \sum a_n x^n$ this implies $\bar a_n =\lambda a_n$
